# VS Code jupyter notebook matplotlib plot directly in plot viewer?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, plot, jupyter

Is it possible to have a matplotlib plot directly displayed in the plot viewer? I am currently working in VS Code on a juptyer notebook, both recently installed/updated. By default, the plot would open inline, like any other result of a cell, and I can open that in the plot viewer by clicking the icon in the top-left corner. Is it possible to have it displayed directly in the plot viewer, without the need to open it manually? I am just trying with something basic, like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Currently VS Code does not support customizing Jupyter's result display method. This is the default way to display the drawing inside Jupyter. And if you want, you could submit this request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will probably submit this request. Hopefully, it might be a useful addition to others too.

Answer (score 0):

Add `%matplotlib qt` to your code before creating the figure/axes  instances

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

%matplotlib qt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y)
```